# Ideal instance type for image resize service

Tags: image-processing, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying an image re-sizer service in ElasticBeanstalk - what instance size should I be using?  t2.medium?

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

The typical image sizes are photos from phones in the 2-10mb range and resizing to jpg from image magick.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends heavily on the usage of the instances. Before settling with some size and type, you should consider what the service is doing, what the traffic (number of requests) will be and how CPU and GPU intense the process is.

For example, Amazon provides also some instances optimized for GPU performance (G2 family).

Take a look at the various [instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) and how they might correspond to your service.

Also, taken from Amazon documentation:

> The c3.8xlarge instance type is ideal for compute-intensive workloads,
>   perfect for image processing and other CPU-bound workloads.  It comes
>   with 32 vCPUs, 60 GiB of memory, 2 x 320 GB SSD storage, and 10
>   Gigabit network connectvity.

I also recommend reading through the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html) and checking the [pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) to find the best instance type to fit your needs.

Comment: considering that its just image resizing from a large number of users - would it be better to say have 8 small instances or instead have one large instance?

Comment: Again, that depends. Are the users from the same region or are they spanned around the world? Will the service be under heavy utilization all the time or during some frequent hours? Are you going to buy reserved instances to save money or just rely on OnDemand instances?

Comment: All over the world, small to heavy utlilization at all hours, lots of 2-3mb sized images - and on demand instances since we don't know what utilization will be - elasticbeanstalk was chosen so that it can scale to this kind of highly variable usage, so the question is if it hits heavy utilization is it better to have a lot of small instances or fewer bigger ones?

Comment: In that case it really depends on the utilization. You can have instances in different regions to ensure good timeouts to all users. If you are sure that the small instances have enough "horsepower" to perform the task then go for them (since they will be OnDemand, they will be more flexible in scaling). Hope it helps